# Bitcoind compilation in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

When I try to compile bitcoind on a Ubuntu 10.04 machine I do:

```
make -f makefile.unix
```

but get errors such as:

```
In file included from db.cpp:6:
db.h:14:20: warning: db_cxx.h: No such file or directory
In file included from db.cpp:6:
db.h:42: error: 'DbEnv' does not name a type
```

I wonder what could be the error. In mac os x, I could compile it wothout problem.

Comment: You can install bitcoin from this PPA on Ubuntu, must you not know: ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin (https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libdb++-dev`